# is coding important?

Tags: computer-science, coding

Is coding important to be good at computer science? Should one implement the algorithm to know it well ?

I remember one cs professor's idiom that "**I never code"**

Comment: You're asking a group of Programmers if coding is important... you might not exactly get an unbiased response.

Comment: With all due respect to your professor's idiom, if he doesn't write code, he's not qualified to teach others how to write code. If his teaching is purely theoretical, it would still benefit from having coding skills.

Comment: Would you take swimming lessons from someone who couldn't swim?

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe: i think the non-swimmer professor teaches aquatic physiology, not swimming.  Still, if he doesn't swim, I'd doubt he knows how nitrogen narcosis feels.

Comment: @Javier: more likely he's teaching underwater demolitions, yet isn't even SCUBA certified. The technical term for people like that (other than "professor") is "poseur" ;-)

Comment: With all due respect, this is the programmers' SE, and coding is obviously important to programmers. If what you care about is computer science, you'd be better off asking in the appropriate forum, say http://cstheory.stackexchange.com . (I'd imagine that the answer would be something like: if your area is algorithms, then coding often helps; if your area is computability theory aka recursion theory, there's really not much you *can* code; if you're doing compiler design or programming languages you *must* know how to code but in practice you can leave much of it to grad students, etc.)

Comment: Who knows, do it, who don't know, teach it :-)

Comment: CS courses always seem to either have too much coding (where you just learn Java and that's it) or not enough (all maths so you know Calculus and Linear Algebra but not much else). Why are there no middle paths?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**You won't really know the algorithm *well* until you code it.**

Comment: this is not necessarily true, one can understand an algorithm and apply it to a situation or problem without actually coding it.

Comment: @aggietech: I think the key word here is *"well."*

Comment: @aggietech, Robert's got it right.  I can parrot out algorithms, but when I really try to make them work, I find out just how much I have to learn about it.

Comment: if you're talking about for-loops and bubble-sorts, then it's no big deal, but there's a huge difference between reading a book on the genetic algorithm and actually solving real-world problems with it

Comment: @Steven, yep, the complexity has a lot to do with it.

Comment: +1 For the Genetic Algorithm comment, as well as the "well" point :)

Comment: This is an answer to the second sentence in the question body, but there is, of course, more to computer science than algorithms (and things that can be coded on a computer).

Comment: I don't think it is true that "you won't really know the algorithm well until you code it." For instance, I designed a small DSL for coding algorithms in the format common to formal languages textbooks. One I could talk about sets and constructs common to these algorithms, I could code them in less time than it would take to understand them.

Answer (score 20):

Coding is not important to your professor, but you need to keep in mind that he is not paid to DO things.  He is paid to SAY things (and WRITE things.)

I'm a former math professor, so I understand this dynamic well.

If you want to follow his path, and to be a theoretical computer scientist, then yes, coding is of lesser importance.  But if you do, remember to maintain humility, knowing that your salary is paid by resources earned by those that chose to DO things.

Comment: The voice of experience.  This is about the best summary of professorship I think I've seen.

Comment: Yes, and I'd add you need to practice the "do" if you are going to teach others to "do" well.

Comment: @BitOff: I agree, but the "if" is also an "only if". A professor who never codes has no business teaching software development, but he may be perfectly suited to teaching, say, complexity theory. In this case, what he's teaching students is how to prove theorems, so the only requirement is that he needs to have practice proving theorems (not coding).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes I agree. And I'm actually not all that strict on the fact that they code a lot in practice. Good coders rarely make good teachers. If the teacher knows their week points they can make up for it. We have a program locally that brings in industry people into the classroom. The teacher is an expert at teaching, can code, and knows how to draw the information out of the industry person for the benefit of the students.

Answer (score 15):

> Computer Science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes

<sup>— Edsger Dijkstra</sup>

I tend to agree.

Comment: Ok, but how does this relate to the question?

Comment: "Is coding important to be good at computer science?" If a computer isn't related how could the physical coding of the computer be important?

Comment: "There’s a difference between a telescope builder and an astronomer, of course. A telescope builder is likely to know more about the construction of telescopes and less about the motion of stellar bodies. But both will have a solid understanding of what happens to light as it travels through the lenses and bounces off the mirrors. Without this understanding, astronomy is very difficult...

Comment: The same principle holds true for computer science. A computer scientist may not fabricate her own ICs, and may not write her own compiler and operating system. In the modern age, these things are generally too complicated for a single person to do to a standard where the result can compete with off-the-shelf components. But the computer scientist definitely will understand what’s happening in the compiler, operating system, and CPU when a program is compiled and run." --http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1083188

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Computer Science is not explicitly about computers, and plenty of astronomers spend little time looking through glass lens.  Some just analyse the results.  Half of the important discoveries in computer programming were known before the computer even came to be.

Comment: @Robert Harvey:Computer science is simply not about how to program, it is the science of computation. Outside pure binary encoding you use a language, which is an abstraction, to implement the theories and findings of computer science. There are many ideas in computer science (e.g. quantum computing) that programming cannot fully realize. All I am saying is that all the ideas of computer science can be fully and elegantly expressed without using a programming language. Name one that can't.

Comment: Just for context: Dijkstra, an enormously important person in computer science who even considered himself a programmer, not only didn't use a computer but didn't even use a typewriter, writing with fountain pens (or was it quills?).

Comment: @Orbling: Very true. For example, recall that Turing invented the notion of the universal Turing machine before the first electronic computer was even created. Does the fact that he didn't write tons of code make him an incompetent computer scientist?

Comment: @mipadi: Not at all.  Turing was one of the great fathers of computation.  Like I say, most of the great work was done before computers existed.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR actually, Dijkstra DID work on comptuers. He even worked on an operating system and programming language compilers. He just knew that the mathematics and formalisms and in general, *thinking*, were more important than banging out hundreds of lines of code.

Answer (score 11):

If you're talking about being a pure Computer Science academic specializing in abstract, foundational Computer Science concepts, then not necessarily.

To bend an analogy: this is a bit like asking if every rocket scientist at NASA should have to fly in space to be a "good rocket scientist". Of course not. Being an astronaut is part of the space flight industry, and a very hands-on part, but it doesn't mean that ground scientists aren't just as important in their own way.

That said, it's probably a good idea to APPLY the algorithm he created, if not actually write it in a real programming language. In this sense, you can think of algorithm design as a branch of mathematics.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that all rocket scientists at NASA have a thorough grounding in rocket science, and in-depth, hands-on experience with mechanical and electrical engineering. Oh, and they generally know how to write code, too.

Comment: I would think that they've calculated trajectories many times, not just theorized about how.

Comment: @Guzica "algorithm design as a branch of mathematics" It is most most controversial topic that I will ask a question about it

Comment: +1, I'd add  another example - you don't need to have experience in wine-making to be a great somellier (or whatever the wine-tasting guys are called).

Comment: @Jas: Terrible analogy. Computer scientists aren't the receivers of the end product. They _are_ the wine-makers.

Comment: @Axidos No, no, they are the *grape farmers*.

Comment: @Mark C: I'm going to take that as a sign we should really drop the analogies for lack of any clear parallels.

Comment: @Axidos: I agree that my analogy is a tad weak, in hindsight. :) Maybe a better one is mechanical engineers working on racing cars? - eg. They don't have to be great drivers themselves.

Comment: @Guzica: Another end-user/producer confusion. No, one of Adobe's main Photoshop programmers could be a terrible digital artist but that doesn't even matter. If I had a penny for every decent analogy I've read on this page I wouldn't have any pennies at all.

Comment: @Axidos - get a grip. Analogies are by definition shallow and imprecise - they are not meant to be a god given word but a nice and reasonably correct illustration on the point.

Comment: @Axidos: Who says a "Computer Scientist" has to be a "producer"? The context of OP's question was academic. I've had profs like this too. They were great in mathematical/algorithmic foundation subjects, even though they hadn't coded in years, and possibly never professionally. But I agree that my analogies failed - I was reaching for a producer analogy too much. Should have just stuck with "teaching versus doing" analogies. :)

Comment: @Guzica: They don't have to be; they almost certainly are in the user/producer dichotomy though. @Jas: Yes, but their point is to establish a parallel & clearer situation and work within (not ignore) those parallels. To repair the Rocket analogy: _Rocket Scientist_ to _Computer Scientist_, _Blueprint Designer_ or _Builder_ to _Programmer_, _Astronaut_ to _End User of Software_. A rocket scientist wouldn't have to know how to make a blueprint (which may be true?) or possibly build a ship. _Now_ we find the imprecise part, where this might not match up to what a Computer Scientist must know.

Answer (score 9):

Coding is not super important to be a true computer scientist. And thinking in code can constrain thinking as they seek to develop useful abstract concepts. Most excellent coders do not have the intellectual chops to analyze complex algorithms, or develop concepts such as programming languages, advanced searching and sorting  algorithms, finite automata theory, distributed computing theory, R-Trees,  fault-tolerance protocols, reliable communication protocols, digital signal processing algorithms, cryptographic theory, performance analysis and optimization, efficient caching, map-reduce, reliable security protocols etc. Excellent coders and computer engineers can usually use these theories in the systems that they are trying to build and do it quite effectively, but that is really the realm of the computer systems engineer or computer programmer.

Coding is critically important to being a computer programmer. Understanding how to encode the useful abstract concepts produced by the computer scientists into working code is also useful.

One big problem in computer science is that they often have to find solutions to math problems that have little utility in solving today's programming problems. Even if they coded a solution, nobody would really be able to use it. Think about digital signal processing theory. It was invented by folks like Fourier, Hilbert and Shannon, but the application to computerized DSP problems was not widely possible until about 20 years ago.

The big problem in computer education is that most people taught by computer scientists will not become computer scientists. But too many computer scientists don't get this. Coding may not be important to them, but if you are in their class, it is almost certainly going to be important to you.

Another big problem in computer education is that many true computer scientists lack the industrial experience to be useful in teaching software development. They are essentially trying to teach something that they really don't know. That causes them to lose credibility. Things that are important in an industrial setting just don't often register with some of these computer scientists.

The long and the short, coding is important for most people who become "computer scientists" because most of those people will become computer programmers and computer system engineers.

Comment: Excellent answer, straight to the heart of the issue.  Problem is, you need to learn both: Computational Science and Software Engineering relevant to industry.  Most universities teach one better than the other, usually the former - it is not overly easy to achieve the latter as a university is inherently a research institute, which promotes the former and has little to do with the latter.  This is an issue in most practical fields.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the subfield the professor is in.

Anybody competent in numerical analysis is probably a Fortran whiz.  Any AI professor will code in Lisp or Prolog or something like that.

In some of the more mathematical areas, there really isn't a need to code.  I'd still be a touch suspicious, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like hes more of a discrete mathematics kind of guy... just into the math and theory behind computer science. Take what these types of professors have to say with a grain of salt.

Comment: I'm math enthusiast and algorithms addict. I always enjoy coding. However, algorithms are behind the coding. 1 pen and 1 paper is enough for algorithms and also theory of computation I think. What I do nowadays is just thinking and writing algorithms but not coding

Comment: Take what any professor says with a grain of salt.  If he's a discrete math guy, take him seriously when he talks about discrete math, not when he talks about programming or software engineering.

Comment: Discrete maths guys are amongst the most important in the field, theory is implemented by coders, it does not need implementing to be proved correct.  Pinch of salt indeed.

Comment: @Orbling And take what those who program say (a broad group) with a similar dose of suspended judgment and common sense.

Comment: @Mark C: Well yes, I would urge everyone to take everything that is said by anyone with those doses.

Answer (score 2):

This is like asking if all English professors should be capable of writing movies, TV series, novels, plays and poems to my mind.  Similarly, imagine a Math professor that never uses numbers for an equally outlandish idea.  That is to say that there are some basic elements that do give coding some importance in being able to teach basic Computer Science.  Thus the professor should know basic language syntax and how to write programs as sophisticated as the courses that the professor is teaching.  If the professor is teaching about compiler design and never wrote a compiler before, this would be a major problem.  Imagine a chef cooking a cake that has never cooked or ate a cake previously.  Aye carumba.

While I can see some advantages to implementing an algorithm to know it, I doubt it is a requirement.  After all, one could wonder how far down the rabbit hole of implementation does one go in understanding how an algorithm is implemented?  For example does someone have to take any algorithm and implement it under various paradigms like procedural, Object-oriented, and functional programming to really know it?  Do they have to know how compilers translate all the code and move the bits around on an electron-by-electron level to be rather pedantic about it.

---

"I never code," does have an implication of containing the past as well as present tense in a way though.  There can also be an implicit assumption of "coding" as a lowly thing that is below the professor for another way to view the statement that can carry a rather negative tone to it that may not go over well in some circles.

Comment: English professors should know how to write movie scripts if they are teaching others how to write movie scripts.  But all English professors should certainly be capable of writing a very good thesis, if not an actual book.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: The OP's professor didn't say he *can't* code, just that he doesn't. He could be a theoretical computer scientist who spends most of his time researching. As JB King pointed out, as long as he's not lecturing on, say, compiler design or software engineering, he could very well be experienced and competent within his field.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I think @mipadi has the point there, the professor just said *"I never code"*, not that he is incapable.

Comment: @JB King, @Orbling: i'd bet that the quote is a translation, so don't overanalyse it literally.

Comment: @Javier: Could well be, in which case it would be even less clear cut.

Answer (score 2):

You can get away with understanding the theory only but I always found I understood algorithms and such 1000x better after having coded them (Bubble sort vs. Quicksort for example, it is great to know the Big-O but seeing it in practice with large data-sets gives you a certain real world appreciation for measuring computational complexity).

One interesting thing I have found is the more you study the theoretical aspets of computer science the easier coding becomes.  At some point you stop thinking of things in a particular language but rather see them just as the broader concepts of computer sience.

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say **"Logic is important"**

Comment: Ok, but how does this relate to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Your professor may be right a bit, in that to be a professor you don't need to code, but knows much about the theory. But that will not work outside the university perimeters.

Answer (score 1):

Despite being a professional software developer, I got a degree in Mechanical Engineering.

You can be a good mechanical designer with very little experience building and machining parts, leaving that job to machinists. But knowing how to build and machine parts will make you a significantly better engineer, because you can predict difficulties involved with fabricating and assembling whatever you are designing.

The same goes for software. A "coder" is a machinist or technician, while a software engineer is, well, the engineer. For many places, one person does both jobs. It's not impossible, and for some very abstract issues, a "engineering only" position might work.

But for the vast majority, there is absolutely no benefit from refusing to code.

Comment: But, as you said, you're a mechanical *engineer*, and you're talking about software *engineering*. Engineers build stuff. But the professor in question teaches computer *science*.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're contemplating and end to the halting problem, there's always a use for coding in every aspect of Computer Science.

The only CS class I took with absolutely no programming was theory. I'd imagine there are plenty of physicists out there who say, "I never experiment" but they're probably also the ones who say, "I never discover anything".  And I'd be surprised if they care.

Comment: In my Computing degree, (with a university in the top 10 internationally, so not something lame), I would say at least a third of my classes had no programming in them whatsoever.  Computing is about far more than code.

Comment: Ok, well apparently I went to a top ten university as well, we may have even went to the same university and taken different classes based on our own likes or dislikes or gotten professors of one ilk or another at random.

Answer (score 0):

As a Computer Science student i think that at first it's better to understand concepts that involve software development. Once you have learned the idea behind software and how does it interacts with a computer, then is time to start coding and dealing with specific implementation problems.

This is just like "Software Exceptions", at first you only deal with them because you did something that was not allowed to do. Then when you learn them, start doing the same with your code so to make it more verbose.

Well i think that people who dont care about concepts like those programmers who use Exceptions as a normal workflow in their applications. They know HOW but dont really get WHY.

Answer (score -6):

I've got another idiom for your professor:

**Those who can, do, those who can't, teach.**

imo, talk is cheap.  Anyone can endlessly jabber on about 'theory' and call it 'computer science'.  But until its put into actual practice, theory isnt very useful because there's no way to validate it.  I'd take a prof's opinion about something *much more seriously* if I knew he's actually *solved* a particular problem in code than if he's just regurgitating 'theory' which may or may not have any supporting evidence to *back up* his point of view.

Comment: "Back up his point of view?" In science, a belief doesn't mean much; you have to *prove* your assertions. How do you know this professor hasn't published pages and pages of proof about his research?

Comment: An awful lot of what is taught in CS is opinion, even if its taught as fact.  If a prof says 'use X to solve this problem', I'd want to know he's actually solved that problem using X.

Comment: Einstein, Aristotle, Webster, Ayn Rand, Thoreau, Confucius and Booker T. Washington were teachers. What an uneducated statement.

Comment: @jeff, All of which had substantial accomplishments *outside* of the classroom.  Compare Ayn Rand, someone who had actually written and published books to an English prof who merely *talks* about writing but has never actually written a book.  Thats basically what the OP's professor is bragging about.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: The OP's professor is a *computer science* professor. The OP's anecdote says nothing about the professor's research accomplishments inside or outside of the classroom.

Comment: @jeff: This is a quote from George Bernard Shaw.  He was certainly not uneducated.

Comment: -1 For a hugely insulting comment to teachers.  Oft quoted I know, but always ridiculous.  The original remark by George Bernard Shaw was "He who can, does. He who cannot, teaches." from *Man and Superman, 1903* - he also said: *"To me the sole hope of human salvation lies in teaching."* and was a co-founder of the London School of Economics (LSE), so you judge his view.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Ayn Rand is however, possibly the most vile person that ever lived.  So is not the best example.

Comment: @Orbling, Ayn Rand was Jeff O's example (see above). And the point stands. Who would you rather have for a writing professor... someone who actually authors and publishes books, or a wannabe who hasnt and seems to take it as a point of pride?

Comment: @GrandmasterB Not to be critical or contentious, but the act of publishing and selling books does not necessarily imply quality of writing and morals.

Comment: @Mark, you're right, it doesnt.  Though it certainly implies that the writer is at least familiar with the process.  On the other hand, *not* writing and publishing a book implies *absolutely nothing* about a professor's actual value to a student.  So again, who would you rather have as a writing professor... someone who actually writes and publishes books, and thus at the very least can provide some real-world insight to the student, or someone who's content to sit around and just jabber about theory, with no evidence they have the slightest real understanding of what they are talking about?

Comment: Einstein never conducted a physical experiment in his life — he did describe a few thought experiments, which were carried out by others and (with one exception) came out exactly as he predicted. Would you say that Einstein had no "substantial accomplishment outside of the classroom"? Why do you assume that just because the professor hasn't implemented anything directly usable by end-users, he hasn't, say, researched a new algorithm that *is* used by programmers in the field? In fact, you seem to even assume that the professor's job is to teach students *how to code*!

Comment: @GrandmasterB: The problem is that in this case, the act of programming is not inherent to all lecturers/professors in computational science, as the discipline is wider than that - which you are missing.  If he were teaching programming, then yes.  Similarly, many English professors teach analysis and understanding of text, you do not need to have written noteworthy examples to understand it pretty well.  Einstein never personally created a nuclear reaction, but his work laid the grounds.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Great minds think alike, I posted my comment on Einstein and see you did the same while I was typing. ;-)

Comment: If the OP's comp sci prof was Einstein, or has otherwise contributed as much to society, then I'll give him a pass.  But chances are he isnt and hasnt.  I live within walking distance of one of the largest univs in the US, and I've met some amazing academics, and they all *do* stuff in their field.  I've never met an archeologist who brags that they dont dig holes, for example.  So when a comp sci prof says he doesnt code, thats an indication that maybe he shouldnt be teaching.

Comment: Dude, lots of my computer science professors (at MIT) were awesome and have contributed immensely to society, and they *do* "do stuff in their field" — a lot! But their field has very little to do with coding, and they code at most very rarely, if at all. (Seriously, do you expect someone working on quantum computation to write code for quantum computers which don't even exist?) You seem to have a very narrow view of computer science. (Remember it's computer *science*, not *engineering*.)

Comment: @GrandmasterB: If a comp sci professor focuses on the theory of computation, it's highly likely he rarely has to write code. That doesn't mean he's not doing anything in his field -- he's likely publishing papers on computational theory! You're conflating *programming* with *computer science*.

Comment: @Don Roby - There are many great people who may have made statements that were accurate at the time, but are no longer valid. Continuing to be misinformed is not what continued education is about.

Comment: @Jeff O - I have never agreed with the Bernard Shaw quote.  I've been a teacher, and find the quote clever but insulting.  Simply saying he was certainly not uneducated.